# How to split money between two devs of a Play Store app

Tags: online-payment, payment, italy, google

Me and a collaborator made an android application and now want to sell it on the Play Store. We would like to know if it's possible to automatically split the money 50/50 between us in some way. As far as we know, Google Merchant doesn't allow for such an option.

PS: We both live in Italy, if that is important.

Edit: we are both university students, we don't own a company or something similar.

Comment: What about creating a joint bank account, and having the money go there?

Comment: We thought about that, but we fear we might lose money with the fees in the long run

Comment: If your bank fees exceed your app earnings, either the app isn’t selling well or your bank fees are exorbitant.

Comment: If the income is so small that it's smaller than the fees on a simple checking account, then it's probably too small to be worrying about. Pay one person and get them to give a few Euros to the other every month or so.